# how to make the bot respond only to add_reaction on the same message?

Tags: python, discord.py

```
def isAdmin(reaction, user):
    for i in admins:
        if user.id == i: return (str(reaction.emoji) == '' or str(reaction.emoji) == '')
try: reaction, user = await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=43200, check=isAdmin)
except asyncio.TimeoutError: await msg.edit(embed=embedEnd)
else:
    resign_channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name="resignings") 
    if str(reaction.emoji) == '':
        print('{}: {} resigned {} {}.'.format(extCalls.timeNow('datetime'), ctx.channel.category.name, firstName, lastName))
        await msg.edit(embed=embedFin)
        await resign_channel.send(embed=embedConf)
    else: await msg.edit(embed=embedEnd)
```

This is my code to have the bot wait for a reaction on `msg`. But, for some reason, when I have two `msg` (messages) waiting for a reaction at the same time, when I react to one message, *both* trigger success, even though I didn't react to the second message. This is hugely problematic for an admin-based approval system... does anyone know why this is happening or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is really messy, but if you're searching for a way to wait only for a reaction on one message you should add stuff to your check command, for example:

```
@bot.command(name="some_command")
async def sc(ctx):
    msg = await ctx.send("Some interesting message!")
    def check(reaction, user):
        return reaction.message.id == msg.id
    try:
        reaction, user = await bot.wait_for("reaction_add", check=check,timeout=30.0)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send("timeout")
        return
    await ctx.send(f"You reacted {str(reaction)}")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You made my day :D